# ComboBox SelectedValue property doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to add objects into a combobox and use `SelectedValue` property to select and item in the combobox but it does not work: `SelectedValue` is still null after the assignment.

```
        class ComboBoxItem
        {
            string name;
            object value;

            public string Name { get { return name; } }
            public object Value { get { return value; } }

            public ComboBoxItem(string name, object value)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.value = value;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                ComboBoxItem item = obj as ComboBoxItem;
                return item!=null && Value.Equals(item.Value);
            }
        }          

            operatorComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("Gleich", SearchOperator.OpEquals));
            operatorComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("Ungleich", SearchOperator.OpNotEquals));


            operatorComboBox.ValueMember="Value";
            //SelectedValue is still null after this statement
            operatorComboBox.SelectedValue = SearchOperator.OpNotEquals;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ValueMember` is only applicable when databinding via `DataSource` property, not when you add items manually with `Items.Add`. Try this:

```
var items = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
items.Add(new ComboBoxItem(...));

operatorComboBox.DataSource = items;
```

Btw, note that when you override `Equals`, you should also override and implement `GetHashCode`.