# Read value from Combobox in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception

I am building a Windows forms application using VS2010. I want to read the value the user selected from the dropdown `ComboBox` and generate `patientNo` based on that. But when i run the application I get a `NullReferenceException`.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string patientNumber;

    string gender = comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
    if (gender != null)
    {
        if (gender == "Female")
        {
            var generator = new PatientNumberGenerator();
            patientNumber = generator.GeneratePatientNumber(Gender.Female);
            const string message = "patientNumber";

            const string caption = "Testing PatientNumber class";
            var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                         MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        }
        else if (gender == "Male")
        {
            var generator = new PatientNumberGenerator();
            patientNumber = generator.GeneratePatientNumber(Gender.Male);
            const string message = "patientNumber";

            const string caption = "Testing PatientNumber class";
            var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                         MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        }
   }
```

}

Comment: I doubt all of the 8 questions you've asked don't have a correct answer. You need to accept some of them.

Comment: I have some ideas to where the error could be, but it would help when you tell us in which line you get the exception, also I won't give an answer if you are not going to accept it later like with the other questions you didn't accept an answer for.

Comment: How are you initializing the combobox?  `comboBox2.SelectedValue` could be null

Comment: Which line thows the exception ? 
Have you tried using a breakpoint to check the value of the combobox selected value?
And the fact that you never accept any answers won't help you on this site.

Comment: I will accept when is work pls

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't said which line the exception is occuring on, so it's a bit of a shot in the dark. However:

```
string gender = comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

`comboBox2.SelectedValue` might be null, in which case trying to call `ToString()` on it would cause a NullReferenceException. Try:

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedValue == null)
{
    return;
}
string gender = comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
//[etc…]
```

If that's not your issue, the exception may be inside other calls in that method, such as `GeneratePatientNumber`.

Comment: In your example, if it ever gets to the ToString line the SelectedValue will always be null

Comment: The exception is no more after your correction but Nothing is displayed on the Messagebox.

Comment: Then you need to find out why SelectedValue is always null, which is difficult to work out from the code posted. Maybe one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867784/winforms-combobox-selectedvalue-is-null) [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408492/combobox-selectedvalue) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140910/combobox-selectedvalue-property-doesnt-work) will help.

Answer (score 3):

If somewhere in your code you are setting `comboBox2.DataSource` property to some datasource, then `.SelectedValue` will retrieve a value.  If you are **not** setting the `.DataSource` property, then `SelectedValue` will return null.

I assume that since you keep getting null values you are not setting a datasource but instead setting your Items in the VS Designer. If that's the case, you should instead be using:

```
comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

to retrieve the SelectedItem in your list.

Comment: you don't have to use a datasource to use SelectedItem.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, but if you _don't_ use a datasource (as I suspect is how the OP is doing it) then you _do_ have to use SelectedItem.

Comment: Thanks BradRem You really explained the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `combobox1.SelectedValue` in `case` use:

```
string selected = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only place I can see you would get a NullReferenceException other than in GeneratePatientNumber is

```
comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

If nothing is selected `.SelectedValue` will be null therefore cannot have `ToString()` called on it.

Comment: @ecomma, `.Text` returns a string anyway so there is no need for the `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is over a year old but I was working on a similar project with the exact same error. What fixed it for me was using

```
comboBox2.SelectedText.ToString();
```

or

```
comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
```